# Unable to install Ubuntu 16.04 on windows 10 via virtualbox

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I'm trying to set up ubuntu on my windows machine using virtualbox but I keep getting the following error after a few seconds of running the installation:

```
end kernel panic - not syncing: vfs: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)
```

I have ensured that Hyper V is disabled and virtualization is enabled in BIOS (those are the suggestions I found online)
This is my first time trying to use Linux. I got the iso file from the ubuntu website

How do I fix this

Comment: I don't run Linux already. I have no access to 'grub' or 'sudo'

Comment: you are right. my bad. you need to change virtual hdd controller type  used for the guest in virtualbox to SATA as explained [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=33190).

Comment: It was set to SATA by default. Not working

Comment: The problem was with the iso file. It probably got corrupted during download. I followed the instructions on Ubuntu website to verify that the iso was fine but it failed the test. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If grub is accessible:

Remove old linux kernels, your /boot drive is out of space.

- Boot to grub and click on “Advanced options”
- Select a previous kernel (should boot fine)

login and enter command

```
$ df
```

See if your /boot directory is 100% used
Remove old linux kernels

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
```

from here: [Geekdecoder](https://www.geekdecoder.com/how-to-fix-kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block00-on-azure-vm)